# SPARQL - how do I convert literals to integer so I can filter my query results?

Tags: filter, sparql, rdf

I made my first RDF (turtle) file about Kim Jong-un. I would like to filter my query results so only his male siblings born before 1984 are shown, but I'm having trouble because these birth years are shown as literals. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

**RDF turtle Data**

(prefixes removed because I needed more reputation points for links)

```
dbp:Kim_Jong-un dbp-ont:sibling wiki-en:Kim_Yo-jong.
wiki-en:Kim_Yo-jong dbp-ont:birthYear        "1987^^xsd:gYear";
foaf:name "Kim Yo-jong";
foaf:gender "female".
```

**SPARQL query**

```
SELECT *
    WHERE {

    dbp:Kim_Jong-un dbp-ont:sibling ?sibling.
    ?sibling foaf:gender ?gender.
    ?sibling foaf:name ?name.
    ?sibling dbp-ont:birthYear ?birthYear.
    FILTER (?gender="male", ?birthYear<"1984")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Compare the lexical form of the literal with the value given as string `STR(?birthYear) < "1984"`(this disables comparison by semantics of the datatype)
2. Use an XPath constructor to get the literal for the given string value `(?birthYear < xsd:gYear("1984"))`

And don't forget to use `&&` to combine multiple expressions in the `FILTER`!